# Android (simple animation creation)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to create a card-based game using java and eclipse to be an android app, i designed the cards (front and back sides), but i can't seem to figure out if i should do the card animation using a third party application or is there a way to animate them using eclipse?

Comment: If you don't understand that Eclipse cannot create animations, then you have a some learning to do.  Please read about the Android SDK and the ADT.  Eclipse is nothing more than an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you really are just doing simple animations, it is pretty easy to do it using standard Android.  You basically create a png for each graphic in your animation, then reference it in the same way you reference any other drawable (with the addition that you tell the system to start your animation).

Bottom line, I would use the built in animation classes, which are simple to use, and much better than integrating (and depending on) a 3rd party library.

Here is a good example about how to do this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-animations-quick-guide.html